# Console errors while hovering on charts in React Highcharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I have created a component for using BarChart and LineChart. When I am hovering on the data points in the said graph, the console is getting filled with errors mentioned below.

Versions Used
`"highcharts": "^10.2.0", "highcharts-react-official": "^2.1.3", "react": "^16.8.6",`

[Sample Image of the Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taneD.png)

1. ```
   highcharts.src.js:24745 Uncaught TypeError: m.call is not a function
       at k.refresh (highcharts.src.js:24745:1)
       at g.<anonymous> (highcharts.src.js:28123:1)
       at x (highcharts.src.js:1660:1)
       at g.firePointEvent (highcharts.src.js:25813:1)
       at f.runPointActions (highcharts.src.js:28121:1)
       at f.onContainerMouseMove (highcharts.src.js:27678:1)
   ```
2. ```
   highcharts.src.js:24745 Uncaught TypeError: m.call is not a function
       at k.refresh (highcharts.src.js:24745:1)
       at g.<anonymous> (highcharts.src.js:28123:1)
       at x (highcharts.src.js:1660:1)
       at g.firePointEvent (highcharts.src.js:25813:1)
       at f.runPointActions (highcharts.src.js:28121:1)
       at g.onMouseOver (highcharts.src.js:26371:1)
       at SVGGElement.e (highcharts.src.js:43249:1)
   ```

Chart Options

```
{
    "chart": {
        "zoomType": "xy",
        "spacingTop": 50,
        "style": {
            "fontFamily": "Work Sans, sans-serif"
        },
        "alignTicks": true
    },
    "colors": [
        "#4a8cb2",
        "#506A78",
        "#bbbbbb"
    ],
    "title": {
        "text": ""
    },
    "subtitle": {
        "text": ""
    },
    "xAxis": {
        "title": {},
        "margin": 25,
        "style": {
            "top": 10
        },
        "categories": [
            "Country: other",
            "USA",
            "Malaysia",
            "India",
            "United Kingdom",
            "Switzerland",
            "South Africa",
            "Singapore",
            "New Zealand",
            "Scotland",
            "China"
        ]
    },
    "tooltip": {
        "formatter": {}
    },
    "yAxis": [
        {
            "title": {
                "text": "ABC"
            },
            "plotLines": [
                {
                    "color": "#D5D5D5",
                    "opacity": 0.5,
                    "dashStyle": "Dash",
                    "width": 2,
                    "org_score": 10,
                    "value": 63,
                    "label": {
                        "align": "right",
                        "style": {
                            "fontWeight": "bold"
                        },
                        "text": "Org Moment Score: 63"
                    },
                    "zIndex": 2
                }
            ],
            "min": null,
            "max": null,
            "allowDecimals": false,
            "showFirstLabel": true,
            "showLastLabel": true,
            "labels": {},
            "opposite": true
        },
        {
            "title": {
                "text": "ABC"
            },
            "allowDecimals": false,
            "gridLineWidth": 0
        }
    ],
    "plotOptions": {
        "column": {
            "stacking": "normal",
            "pointWidth": 20,
            "states": {
                "hover": {
                    "brightness": -0.3
                }
            },
            "dataLabels": {}
        },
        "series": {
            "pointWidth": 15,
            "marker": {
                "fillColor": "#FFFFFF",
                "lineWidth": 2,
                "lineColor": null
            },
            "dataLabels": {}
        }
    },
    "series": [
        {
            "name": "Lorem Ipsum",
            "type": "column",
            "yAxis": 1,
            "data": [
                1,
                73,
                20,
                24,
                49,
                6,
                9,
                14,
                1,
                1,
                1
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Ipsum Lorem",
            "type": "line",
            "color": "#ffdc4c",
            "data": [
                47,
                62,
                63,
                63,
                63,
                63,
                65,
                65,
                81,
                81,
                84
            ]
        }
    ],
    "credits": {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "legend": {
        "enabled": true,
        "margin": 10
    },
    "exporting": {
        "chartOptions": {
            "title": {
                "text": "'Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum"
            }
        },
        "enabled": true,
        "allowHTML": true,
        "sourceWidth": 1200,
        "sourceHeight": 400,
        "csv": {},
        "menuItemDefinitions": {
            "label": {
                "text": "Show-Hide Data Labels"
            }
        },
        "buttons": {
            "contextButton": {
                "align": "right",
                "y": -45,
                "x": -5,
                "menuItems": [
                    "downloadPNG",
                    "downloadJPEG",
                    "downloadPDF",
                    "separator",
                    "label"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "page": "Ipsum Lorem Ipsum"
}
```

Usage:

```
 <HighchartsReact 
   highcharts={Highcharts}
   options={chart_options} 
   allowChartUpdate={true}
   ref={chart_ref}/>
```

Props Passed:

highcharts: Highcharts from highcharts/highstock

ref: React.createRef() passed

I have tried searching for the solution to this issue, but all I have gotten so far is that there are some issues related to tooltips. I can't pinpoint the issue, any help would be appreciated.

https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=42956

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by the following code:

```
 tooltip: {
        formatter: {}
    }
```

In fact, `tooltip.formatter` is a callback function, so should be put this way:

```
    tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {}
    }
```

or omitted if you don't want to format the tooltip.

**Demo:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-forked-0syyvk

**API:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter